# Need help, trying to read a file and fill an array of objects with their parameters in java

Tags: java, arrays

To let you know this is an assignment for my class, I'm just asking for a little help with it. The short form of the assignment is to:

Write an application class that reads a file (from the command line) and fills an array of type vehicle[] with new vehicle 
(params), new car (params), new american car (params) new foreign car(params) , new truck (params),
new bicycle (params), etc.

This is what I have so far(I have already written individual classes for each of the objects that all extend vehicle):

```
  public class n01029506{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{   
     Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
     ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();

  while(input.hasNext()){
     if(input.nextLine().equals("vehicle")){
        String name = input.nextLine();
        String address = input.nextLine();
        String phone = input.nextLine();
        String email = input.nextLine();       
        list.add(new Vehicle(name, address, phone, email));
     }
    }
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
   }
  }
```

The output of this code is an array of objects called vehicle from the file I am reading. The problem I am having is when I add another else if statement it compiles but I get a runtime error.

```
     if(input.nextLine().equals("vehicle")){
        String name = input.nextLine();
        String address = input.nextLine();
        String phone = input.nextLine();
        String email = input.nextLine();       
        list.add(new Vehicle(name, address, phone, email));
     }else if(input.nextLine().equals("car")){
        String name = input.nextLine();
        String address = input.nextLine();
        String phone = input.nextLine();
        String email = input.nextLine();    
        boolean convert = input.nextBoolean();
        String color = input.nextLine();   
        list.add(new Car(name, address, phone, email, convert, color));
     }
```

What I need the program to do is go through and once it reads a line from the file - whether a car, vehicle, etc - it creates and object and stores it in the array. I'm not sure how to get the program to work properly. If anyone could help me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Call nextLine() **once**, store the result in a variable, and compare this variable with "vehicle", "car", etc. nextLine() reads the next line **and moves** to the beginning of the next one. You should really be able to figure that out by yourself, by using your debugger, or aven just add System.out.println() traces in the code.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input file? As it's written now, we're to assume that every parameter is written on its own line. If that's not the case, that would quickly break your program.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, I understand now. I completely went brain dead on how else ifs worked and the next statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to spell out what JB Nizet said in the comment. Assume your input file contains:

```
car
Riley Clark
3476 9th Ave N
555-555-1234
rc@toyota.jp
false
blue
```

OK? Now your program reads the line `car` and compares it to `vehicle`. Since they are not the same, it goes into the `else if` part. This will read the line `Riley Clark` and compare it to `car`. They are not the same either. So you program will never discover there’s a car in these lines of the file.

JB Nizet also gave the solution: “Call `nextLine()` **once**, store the result in a variable, and compare this variable with "vehicle", "car", etc.”